# Entity Framework Core import / export tree of entities with similar foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity

I need to add an import/export functionality to my ASP.NET Core application.

What I would like is to take entities in one database, export these entities into one file, and then import that file into a new database.

My problem is that I have some entities that hold same foreign key. Here is a simple model illustrating what I want to do:

```
public class Bill 
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to export a bill to be imported on an other environment of my application. So if I export the bill, I will get a Json like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "products" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "productCategoryId": 1,
            "productCategory": {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "Category #1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "productCategoryId": 1,
            "productCategory": {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "Category #1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "productCategoryId": 1,
            "productCategory": {
                "id" : 2,
                "name" : "Category #2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I deserialize this json into entities in my new environment (ignoring Ids mapping of course), I will get three new categories (category will be duplicated for product 1 and 2) because the serializer will instanciate two categories...

So when I push it into my database, it will add 3 lines instead 2 into the `Category` table...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of `Category` to be imported, you could firstly get the id list of these categories and then query the database to make sure which has been already stored in database. And for those already existing ones, just skip them (or update them as you like).

Since we have multiple entity types (categories,products,bills and potential BillProducts), rather than writing a new importer for each `TEntity` , I prefer to writing a generic `Importer` method to deal with any Entity type list with `Generic` and `Reflection` :

```
public async Task ImportBatch<TEntity,TKey>(IList<TEntity> entites)
    where TEntity : class 
    where TKey: IEquatable<TKey>
{
    var ids = entites.Select( e=> GetId<TEntity,TKey>(e));
    var existingsInDatabase=this._context.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(e=> ids.Any(i => i.Equals(GetId<TEntity,TKey>(e)) ))
        .ToList();

    using (var transaction = this._context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try{
            this._context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + typeof(TEntity).Name + " ON;");
            this._context.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var entity in entites)
            {
                var e= existingsInDatabase.Find(existing => {
                    var k1 =GetId<TEntity,TKey>(existing); 
                    var k2=GetId<TEntity,TKey>(entity);
                    return k1.Equals(k2);  
                });
                // if not yet exists
                if(e == null){
                    this._context.Add(entity);
                }else{
                    // if you would like to update the old one when there're some differences
                    //    uncomment the following line :
                    // this._context.Entry(e).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                }
            }
            await this._context.SaveChangesAsync();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch{
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally{
            this._context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + typeof(TEntity).Name + " OFF;");
            await this._context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Here the `GetId<TEntity,TKey>(TEntity e)` is a simple helper method which is used to get the `key` filed of `e`:

```
    // use reflection to get the Id of any TEntity type
    private static TKey GetId<TEntity,TKey>(TEntity e)
        where TEntity : class
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        PropertyInfo pi=typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id");
        if(pi == null) { throw new Exception($"the type {typeof(TEntity)} must has a property of `Id`"); }
        TKey k = (TKey) pi.GetValue(e);
        return k ;
    }
```

To make the code more reusable, we can create an `EntityImporter` service to hold the method above :

```
public class EntityImporter{
    private DbContext _context;

    public EntityImporter(DbContext dbContext){
        this._context = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task ImportBatch<TEntity,TKey>(IList<TEntity> entites)
        where TEntity : class 
        where TKey: IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static TKey GetId<TEntity,TKey>(TEntity e)
        where TEntity : class
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

and then register the services at startup time:

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, AppDbContext>();
services.AddScoped<EntityImporter>();
```

**Test Case :**

Firstly, I'll take several categories as an example :

```
var categories = new ProductCategory[]{
    new ProductCategory{
        Id = 1,
        Name="Category #1"
    },
    new ProductCategory{
        Id = 2,
        Name="Category #2"
    },
    new ProductCategory{
        Id = 3,
        Name="Category #3"
    },
    new ProductCategory{
        Id = 2,
        Name="Category #2"
    },
    new ProductCategory{
        Id = 1,
        Name="Category #1"
    },
};

await this._importer.ImportBatch<ProductCategory,int>(categories);
```

The expected results should be only 3 rows imported :

```
1 category #1
2 category #2 
3 category #3
```

And here's a screenshot it works:

[image]

Finally, for your bills json, you can do as below to import the entites :

```
var categories = bill.Products.Select(p=>p.ProductCategory).ToList();
var products = bill.Products.ToList();
// other List<TEntity>...

// import the categories firstly , since they might be referenced by other entity
await this._importer.ImportBatch<ProductCategory,int>(categories);
// import the product secondly , since they might be referenced by BillProduct table
await this._import.ImportBatch<Product,int>(products);
// ... import others
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.

The problem is that you import on the new database the same ids than on the previous... so i can get conflict !
What i want is to get so new ids generated by the destination database, that's why it is a bit hard to keep foreign keys... Because my only solution to say EntityFramework that two newly created entities are the same in database is to have exactly the same reference each time an entity is used as foreign key.

Comment: @FabienDezautez, So, if I understand correctly,  a category of `{Id:99, Name:"Category #1"}` within you json  is exactly the same as `{Id:66, Name:"Category #1"}` in database  ?

Comment: No, the category 99 and 66 are different. But these ids come from the source database and can be already used on the destination database

Comment: @FabienDezautez  Think about you have `[{Id:66, Name:"Category #1"},{Id:99, Name:"Category #1"}]` within the source database, and the id=66 has already been taken by dest database , and the new inserted record for id=66 will be `[{Id:1106, Name:"Category #1"}]` , what about the id=99 from source database ? should they considered as the same ?

Comment: @FabienDezautez  If the `src`'id has already been taken by `dest` database, and their Names are exactly the same, should they be considered as the same ? If not, In which case , should we consider they are duplicated ?

Comment: @FabienDezautez Before anyone could make suggestion, we have to understand  if user import the json multiple times,  how can you determine whether a record from source database is duplicated . Since the id from source database is probably taken by destination database, we must check it in other ways. If you could control the serialization from source database, I recommend you could add a HASH filed as a fingerprint or simply use the Name field as an identifier.

Comment: In fact, i have two possibilities. 
First : i want that if i find a category with the same name (but different ID of course), i replace the other fields of the dest category by the values given from src. 

Second option : i use the existing category without update.

The json can eventually be imported a second time but the user will have to specify if conflicts are merged or not.

Comment: @FabienDezautez So the `Name` field will be an identifier for the 1st option?

Comment: Yes i could make the Name as an identifier. 

But my problem is that i will have to iterate on each Products to get all the distinct Categories to be added. And if i do not remove Category on every product before giving the product to the DbContext, dupplicated categories will be in conflict because deserializer will have create different instances.

Am i wrong ?

Comment: In fact i think i have to say my Serializer that in the tree of objects to deserialize,if it finds two objects with same keys, he has to use the same memory reference and not instanciate a new one each time. If not, the dbcontext will track two references and will give a conflict "dupplicated key".

Comment: @FabienDezautez That's not suitable. As it wont stop users to import the same records in different JSON multiple times. The validation must be executed against the destination database.